# How To Create Database Tables in C

Tags: database

I need to code a small/simple database application using C, for my CS degree (so using SQLite or any other available application is not an option. In other words, I do need to re-invent the wheel here).

My idea is to use a B-Tree to store the items of each table. The problem I am facing is that tables need to be flexible to hold an unknown number of columns, and each column can be either a STRING or an INT. For example, with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE student (STRING name, INT age)
```

I would need to create a table that holds a string and an integer. With this command instead:

```
CREATE TABLE grade (INT grade1, INT grade2, INT grade3)
```

I would need to create a table that holds three integers.

How can achieve such flexibility?

My only idea so far is to create a struct with several unions inside it, where each union can be either a STRING or an INT. I would also need to put a lot of unions inside, to be sure to accommodate all the columns requested by the table. For example:

```
struct table{
    union{
        int number;
        char *text;
    }column1;

    union{
        int number;
        char *text;
    }column2;

    union{
        int number;
        char *text;
    }column3;

    ....

};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The better way would be to use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/).

Comment: I updated my question. This is for college, with the purpose of learning. So yeah I pretty much have to invent my own DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can only think of two very different approaches:

1. make a 'schema compiler' that gets the table definition, writes the `struct`s and compiles the database engine.
2. from the schema definition calculate the byte offset and length of each column.  save and restore the records as a byte array and pick the fields using that offset/length list.

most common is #2, but #1 has the advantage that the C compiler 'knows' the table structure, and will type-check your columns.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question and my answer is a bit irrelevant, but I encounter the same issue when I was writing my custom database for fun. However, my solution is to write a native dynamic struct library in **C++** and utilize **OOP** features like virtual function heavily. Maybe, you could find a way to transport it into a C library or get some inspirations to develop your own one.

For your reference, I upload my code to GitHub and here is the link [c++-dynamic-type-library](https://github.com/RaymondJiangkw/c-dynamic-type-library). I illustrate some usages in the README file, and one of them is exactly to create a struct with variable number of properties and types from input (thus could be adapted to CREATE TABLE command). I also write `Serialize` and `Deserialize` function to transform a struct into string and back forth.